# Tortoise tsvn:logminsize help

Tags: tortoisesvn

I want my team inputting at least x # of chars into a commit comment in Tortoise.  Is there a hook to do this?  I guess I need to use a property called tsvn:logminsize but I don't get how to add that property globally for ALL repositories so that anyone on the team is required to input x chars when checking in any code for any project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to the precommit hook in SVN (Tortoise is just a GUI client for SVN, so will have to do it in your SVN server itself).

1. Under your repository directory, you will find hooks/pre-commit.tmpl.
2. Edit this file and save it as pre-commit and make it an executable
3. Check for the comment length inside the file and return a non zero value if it does not have atleast x# characters.

Note that the precommit file can be in any language (python, shell script etc).

More details here [- http://oss.segetech.com/bugz-svn-wiki/pre-commit](http://oss.segetech.com/bugz-svn-wiki/pre-commit)

Comment: thank you, I'll try that instead as this seems more permanent.

Comment: Only problem is running that on a 64-bit OS.  I installed the 64-bit Tortoise but running it as an exe is an issue saying the exe is 32-bit.